# Loading unpacked extensions doesn't work Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

**"This addon could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt"**

I am getting the above error from installing an unpacked extension.
I just unpacked the extension using Winrar and then just dragged the folder to the Firefox addon/extension page.

Plus Zipping it to addon.xpi doesn't work either.

**My Goal** :I am editing an extension to fit my needs and it doesn't seem to work.

I presume Firefox has some kindoff signing or something, how can I disable this or edit the extension to meet the requirements.

I am running **58.0 (64-bit)**

The extension has the following error  when loading using debugging (Mozilla about:debugging)

**Both** the *edited.xpi* and *original.xpi* have the error. (However the **edited.xpi** loads thru the **load temporary extension** but does not load for the dragging method. )

```
Reading manifest: Error processing background.persistent: Event pages are not currently supported. This will run as a persistent background page.
Reading manifest: Error processing permissions.4: Value "identity.email" must either: must either [must either [be one of ["clipboardRead", "clipboardWrite", "geolocation", "idle", "notifications"], be one of ["bookmarks"], be one of ["find"], be one of ["history"], be one of ["activeTab", "tabs"], be one of ["browserSettings"], be one of ["cookies"], be one of ["topSites"], be one of ["webNavigation"], or be one of ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking"]], be one of ["alarms", "mozillaAddons", "storage", "unlimitedStorage"], be one of ["browsingData"], be one of ["devtools"], be one of ["identity"], be one of ["menus", "contextMenus"], be one of ["pkcs11"], be one of ["geckoProfiler"], be one of ["sessions"], be one of ["contextualIdentities"], be one of ["downloads", "downloads.open"], be one of ["management"], be one of ["privacy"], be one of ["proxy"], be one of ["nativeMessaging"], be one of ["theme"], or match the pattern /^experiments(\.\w+)+$/], or must either [be one of ["<all_urls>"], match the pattern /^(https?|wss?|file|ftp|\*):\/\/(\*|\*\.[^*/]+|[^*/]+)\/.*$/, or match the pattern /^file:\/\/\/.*$/]
Reading manifest: Error processing oauth2: An unexpected property was found in the WebExtension manifest.
Reading manifest: Error processing options_page: An unexpected property was found in the WebExtension manifest.
```

Here is the error from the Browser console:

```
          1516983623806 addons.webextension.<unknown>   WARN    Loading extension 'null': Reading manifest: Error processing background.persistent: Event pages are not currently supported. This will run as a persistent background page.
1516983623811   addons.webextension.<unknown>   WARN    Loading extension 'null': Reading manifest: Error processing permissions.4: Value "identity.email" must either: must either [must either [be one of ["clipboardRead", "clipboardWrite", "geolocation", "idle", "notifications"], be one of ["bookmarks"], be one of ["find"], be one of ["history"], be one of ["activeTab", "tabs"], be one of ["browserSettings"], be one of ["cookies"], be one of ["topSites"], be one of ["webNavigation"], or be one of ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking"]], be one of ["alarms", "mozillaAddons", "storage", "unlimitedStorage"], be one of ["browsingData"], be one of ["devtools"], be one of ["identity"], be one of ["menus", "contextMenus"], be one of ["pkcs11"], be one of ["geckoProfiler"], be one of ["sessions"], be one of ["contextualIdentities"], be one of ["downloads", "downloads.open"], be one of ["management"], be one of ["privacy"], be one of ["proxy"], be one of ["nativeMessaging"], be one of ["theme"], or match the pattern /^experiments(\.\w+)+$/], or must either [be one of ["<all_urls>"], match the pattern /^(https?|wss?|file|ftp|\*):\/\/(\*|\*\.[^*/]+|[^*/]+)\/.*$/, or match the pattern /^file:\/\/\/.*$/]
1516983623812   addons.webextension.<unknown>   WARN    Loading extension 'null': Reading manifest: Error processing oauth2: An unexpected property was found in the WebExtension manifest.
1516983623812   addons.webextension.<unknown>   WARN    Loading extension 'null': Reading manifest: Error processing options_page: An unexpected property was found in the WebExtension manifest.
1516983623816   addons.xpi  WARN    Please specify whether you want browser_style or not in your options_ui options.
1516983623829   addons.xpi  WARN    Add-on {487609b5-5ca6-4c62-8523-11f3e1db851c} is not correctly signed.
1516983623830   addons.xpi  WARN    Add-on {487609b5-5ca6-4c62-8523-11f3e1db851c} is not correctly signed.
1516983623830   addons.xpi  WARN    Invalid XPI: signature verification failed
```

Hope fully there is a solution that accomodates intalling the extension without installing through the temporary method.

Comment: If you want a more specific answer, please attach the code so we can look at it.

Comment: @Smile4ever I have added more details above.

Comment: Please attach your manifest.json to the question as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Look in the Browser Console (not Web Console) for errors related to the addon you have loaded.
- Have you tried using `about:debugging`?
- In Firefox Nightly, you can disable the signing by setting `xpinstall.signatures.required` to `false` in `about:config`. On other builds this has no effect for security reasons.

Comment: Is there way to sign my own extension to install to the current version of firefox?

Comment: Upload it to addons.mozilla.org as unlisted (you will need a Firefox account). When unlisted, your addon will not appear in searches. You will need to change the addon id if you want to take that route.

Comment: I did as you advised and it worked, I took the Mozilla Signing route.